# UISearchBar Minimal Style makes tint black when typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

When I set my `UISearchBar` to `minimal style` in iOS7, when I select it the tint becomes black, and the text is impossible to read because there's black on black.

This does not produce the desired result. The tint is still black when selected...

```
if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    // set bar style
    _sendToSearchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    // set bar transparancy
    _sendToSearchBar.translucent = NO;
    // set bar color
    _sendToSearchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // set bar button color
    _sendToSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // set bar background color
    _sendToSearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you are calling any web call on the background event of UISearchBar??

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed What?? No...

Comment: then elaborate your questions.

Comment: are you willing to clear background color of search bar..???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had same problem and tried for few hours, the conclusion is UISearchBar are quite buggy ! Especially in "minimal" mode.

My workaround is :

- Set the search style to Default (Prominent)
- Set the BackgroundImage (Not BackgroundColor) to a transparent image or create an UIImage using `[UIColor clearColor]`
- Set the BarTintColor to `[UIColor blackColor]`
- Set the TintColor to `[UIColor whiteColor]`

The search bar looks like minimal mode in normal,
and the background will be white when selected, so you can see the black color text.

The workaround isn't perfect, it just work, hope can help.

Comment: How would you make a UIImage using a UIColor?

Comment: You can write your own code using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` & `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` method, or there are some open source UIImage class extension : https://github.com/NZN/UIImage-Helpers

Answer (score 11):

i had this bug and after some research i get this code that work! ios 7+

```
//change searchbar color
[searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([UIColor clearColor])]];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 // iOS7 and after
if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    // set bar style
    bar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    // set bar transparancy
    bar.translucent = NO;
    // set bar color
    bar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // set bar button color
    bar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // set bar background color
    bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: my goal is to get everything to be white, and the text color to be black. Your answer does not solve this problem.

Comment: My problem was slightly different that the OP - the text color turned black when typing, which looked horrible on a dark background. This answer helped me find the key settings, which are (in Swift): searchBarStyle (.Minimal), barStyle (.Black or .BlackTranslucent work), backgroundColor (color for entire bar), and tintColor (text color, including when typing). No need for fragile goofiness of other answers. Thanks! BTW OP can use this answer by setting colors for backgroundColor (White) and tintColor (Black).

Answer (score 2):

```
searchField.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[searchField setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Will create a black tinted search bar with white text.

The `appearanceWhenContainedIn` must be called after creating the searchBar and setting the minimal style to actually take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I Discover that if you set both `barstyle` and `searchbarstyle`, searchBar turn to expected minimal style

```
self.itemsSearchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
self.itemsSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit search bar properties to prevent making search bar transparent:

```
self.iSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.iSearchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBackgroundImage.png"] withTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // or you can just create any random plain image with this color and use it with imageNamed: method.
self.iSearchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

For your convenience imageWithImage:withTintColorMethod is defined below:

```
@implementation UIImage (Category)
+ (UIImage *) imageWithImage: (UIImage*) image withTintColor: (UIColor*) color {
    UIImage *newImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImage.size, NO, newImage.scale);
    [color set];
    [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My search bar had a white cursor but when I started typing the text was black. Also my search icon was gray instead of white. I found the solution to this almost by accident.

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(), for: .clear, state: .normal)
```